# error Parsing error: Invalid regular expression flag while deploying function to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

create push notification with node.js for my android chatting app project with firebase. When I deploy my firebase at notification function, I got some error.

This is my index.js at 38 : 11 and 39:16
****This is my index.js****

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notification/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {

const user_id = event.params.user_id;
const notification = event.params.notification;

console.log("The User Id is : ",user_id);

if(!event.data.val()){

return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from database : ', notification_id);
}

const fromUser = admin.database().ref(/notification/${user_id}/{notification_id}).once(value);
return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;
    console.log('You have new notification from : ', from_user_id);

    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
    return userQuery.then(userResult => {

        const userName = userResult.val();
        const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

        return deviceToken.then (result => {

          const token_id = result.val();

          const payload = {
            notification : {

              title : "Friend Request",
              body : `${userName} has sent you request`,
              icon : "default"
            }
          };

          return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id , payload);
        });
  });
});
});
**The cmd give me following result**


C:\Users\Ouneeb Ur Rehman\Desktop\notification function\functions\index.js
  19:40  error  Parsing error: Invalid regular expression flag

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ouneeb Ur Rehman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-23T11_05_23_181Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit 
I try install and uninstall npn and firebase tools but alls goes to vane
```

i got firebase token id and store in database
i am new to node js and cannot u[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1gLa.png)
 Plz any one can help 
    Thanks in advance

this is my notification data base sinpit

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot quotes on line 19 (and should use simple quote : `'`). Firebase Database wants a String, not a regex. (cf : [Reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference))

Line 19 should be :

```
const fromUser = admin.database().ref('/notification/${user_id}/{notification_id}').once(value);
```

Please note that Javascript Regular expression can take the following form:

```
/pattern/replacement/flags
```

That's why elint warns you about an invalid regular expression flag.

Comment: yunandtidu Thanks you for your help its solve my problem

Comment: Thans for remembering me  yunandtidus